# Need to subtract two columns using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, subtraction

I have this query which gives me the number of license used and total number of licenses, but I need to subtract these columns and name result column as "number available".

What I need is (Total number - number of license users = number available)

**Query so far:**

```
SELECT Count(u.user_id) "Number Used",
       kp.temp_num_license
FROM   products p,
       user_products u
WHERE  user_id IN (SELECT user_id
                   FROM   t_users
                   WHERE  end_date IS NULL)
       AND kp.product_id IN ( 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8 )
       AND u.product_id = p.product_id
GROUP  BY temp_num_license
```

I would really appreciate any help on this one.

Comment: In your query you have `kp.temp_num_license`, but there is no table "kp".

Comment: You're referencing `kp` relation in the `SELECT`, `WHERE` and `GROUP BY` operators of your query, but it is not defined. Please, review your query.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Count(u.user_id) "Number Used", kp.temp_num_license, COUNT(u.user_id) - (kp.temp_num_licencse) "Number Available"
FROM products p,user_products u 
WHERE user_id in (select user_id from t_users where end_date is null) and kp.product_id in (2,3,4,5,7,8) AND u.product_id=p.product_id group by temp_num_license
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help Darren your suggestion really worked.